# FOSUserBundle Overriding Problems

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem that i was searching on the interwebz but no solution found!

My problem is: i want to override registration and show fosuserbundle's registration form in my view (or in overrided view). Not working...

Always telling the same story;

Copy to:

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/......

I have already did it!

I have override a controller that works for registration:

```
<?php

namespace CS\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
register:
    pattern: /register
    defaults: { _controller: CSUserBundle:Registration:register }
```

Here is my override directory:

[image]

Comment: You must place the views files here: `app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views` according to your screenshot is: `app\Resources\views\FOSUserBundle\views` so, just delete the first `views` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make the registration form within your template, you could simply override *Resources/views/layout.html.twig*. It is simpler than the override controller, routes, etc.
It is the general layout for FOSUserBundle. [Here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md#example-overriding-the-default-layouthtmltwig) you can find a detailed description on how to do.

Comment: I did it bro... Nothing happens. Maybe i should remove my override controller? :/ I dunno i think i will the form elements only. Whatever, thansk anyway.

Comment: you should try it in the easiest way possible, which is to perform only the overloading of the template (solution a in the link I posted).   
After that you have to completely clear the cache and it should go.   
If it does not work, you should post here the exact path (within your project) of the amended layout.html.twig